# how to get western number pattern (seperated with commas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

my value is coming in input like `3440.00`, But need to show like `3,440.00`

more example: `10,05,000.00` should be `1,005,000.00`

I got my data from spring mvc with thymeleaf

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control inputData"  id="abcd"  th:value="${selectedDetails.abcd}" readonly="readonly"/>
```

js is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

 var a=$("#abcd").val();
 console.log(a);

 function *format(a)* {
  console.log(acquisitionCost);
    return a.toLocaleString("en", {  useGrouping: true,});
}
```

I hope my problem is in Javascript. how I will call method format?

help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below snippet.

```js
function format1(n) {
  n = parseFloat(n);
  return n.toFixed(2).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a = $("#abcd").val();
  console.log(format1(a));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control inputData"  id="abcd"  value="12345.67" readonly="readonly"/>
```

**Update**

```
//Textfield value
var a = $("#abcd").val();
//Number format the value
var formatted_a = format1(a);
```

Comment: How i will call my format(n) function? in my scenario

Comment: Value is loaded in your case with? th:value="${selectedDetails.abcd}"

Comment: yes,, so i got my value in js in "a" variable. but how i call  function *format(a)* {
} or if i used you code how i will  call  function format1(n)., mine is not an array,,is just var a.

Comment: you just have to use 
var a=format1($("#abcd").val()); 
To convert the textfield value.

Comment: @mammam please check updated snippet as well. It might help you.